# Stencil JS typescript - set custom attribute to DIV tag

Tags: typescript, attributes, stenciljs

I have a problem with the latest version of Stencil JS (2.17.0).

I want to put a custom attribute to DIV tag:

The problem is that typescript says:

**Property 'size' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes'**

In previous version of Stencil that I have used, I had a **jsx.d.ts** file, which worked and looks like this:

```
import { JSXBase } from '@stencil/core';

declare namespace JSX {
   interface IntrinsicElements {
      'div': JSXBase.HTMLAttributes & {
          size?: string
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello there, can you please tell us what would the size attribute be good for on a div element? How about using a custom element or a data attribute instead?

Comment: Hi, actually I have resolved my issue by putting "data-size" instead of "size", I have realized it is not such a good idea to put html attributes that are not native for the browsers.